# Autocomplete returns results but does not render menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am unable to render a menu from this autocomplete function. I have tried changing the `items.autocomplete` to `ui-autocomplete-items`.

I have tried using `.autocomplete('instance')` instead of `.data('autocomplete')` and I have also tried inline and externalised functions for overriding `_renderItem` but to no avail. All fail silently to render the menu (inspector shows hidden menu with no items), except that `.autocomplete('instance')` returns `undefined` and as such I cannot add a function to it.

Unfortunately I cannot provide a working demo as the suggestion service is private and proprietary, however I have provided example data below the code for anyone wishing to try and make their own demo (might have to change using JSONP to JSON). I cannot change my code to use JSON though as the service is on another domain and this is the only way to access it.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong here? I have exhausted all other SO threads on this topic and tried just about everything. I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.10.2.

```
var url;

var renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    console.log('rendering item');
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item) // tried replaceing with item.autocomplete
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "<br/>" + item.value + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};

var getSuggestions = function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            postcode: request.term,
            suggestionType: 'FULL',
            resultLimit: 50
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success :: data:');
            console.log(data);
            $.map(data.suggestions, function(obj, i) {
                console.log('success.map :: obj['+i+']:');
                console.log(obj);
                return {
                    label: obj.label,
                    value: obj.data.localityTag.postcode,
                    postcode: obj.data.localityTag.postcode,
                    suburb: obj.data.localityTag.locality,
                    state: obj.data.localityTag.state
                };
            });
        }
    });
};

$(function() {
    url = $('#raetDomain').val() + $('#raetContext').val() + 'getSuggestions';
    window.suggestionSelected = false;
    var autoc = {
        delay: 200,
        minLength: 4,
        source: getSuggestions,
        focus: function(e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault(); // without this: keyboard movements reset the input to ''
            $('#homeAddressFields .addressSuburb').val(ui.item.suburb);
            $('#homeAddressFields .addressPostcode').val(ui.item.postcode);
            $('#homeAddressFields .addressState').val(ui.item.state);
        },
        select: function(e, ui) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.suggestionSelected = true;
            $('#homeAddressFields .addressSuburb').val(ui.item.suburb);
            $('#homeAddressFields .addressPostcode').val(ui.item.postcode);
            $('#homeAddressFields .addressState').val(ui.item.state);
        }
    };

    // This is only one of these fields at the moment but I am aiming for two postcode fields
    // and two suburb fields to all have autocomplete setup on them.
    $('#homeAddressFields .addressPostcode').each(function(i) {
         $(this).autocomplete(autoc).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = renderItem;
         // tried .autocomplete('instance') instead of .data(...) but was undefined
    });
});
```

Sample data (without padding):

```
{
    "suggestions":
    [{
        "data":
        {
            "localityTag":{"locality":"ACTON","postcode":"2601","state":"ACT"}
        },
        "label":"ACTON ACT 2601",
        "value":"ACTON ACT 2601"
    }],
    "suggestionType":"FULL"
}
```

Comment: Did you inspect the generated HTML? Maybe it's there, but the CSS styles have `height:0` or something - happened to me several times.

Comment: The `ui-autocomplete` `UL` element is there, hidden with `display:none` but there are no children. Trying to create a jsfiddle with JSONP, will update Q if I'm successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all sorts of combinations of workarounds I realised the callback wasn't running. It renders the items correctly now I have changed the $.ajax success function to the code below.

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log('success :: data:');
    console.log(data);
    response($.map(data.suggestions, function(obj, i) {
        console.log('success.map :: obj['+i+']:');
        console.log(obj);
        return {
            label: obj.label,
            value: obj.data.localityTag.postcode,
            postcode: obj.data.localityTag.postcode,
            suburb: obj.data.localityTag.locality,
            state: obj.data.localityTag.state
        };
    }));
}
```